# He probably has a very high opinion of himself

Tags: word-choice

What is the best way to describe someone who thinks he is  very knowledgeable on issues like Arts, History and Literature etc.  and behaves like a real scholar, but actually has no adequate studies in his background.

Comment: We should know the way you perceive scholars to behave if we are to give you a word or phrase that fits your needs.

Comment: Sounds like Socrates. I don't think he had adequate studies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that came to mind was the prefix *pseudo*-. From [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/pseudo):

> **pseudo-** (*prefix*) not real, but pretending to be real: used with many nouns and adjectives 
>   *pseudoscientific*

So, you could call them *pseudo-scholars*, or even **pseudoexperts**. One author wrote:

> **Pseudo-experts don't understand, and so they tend to look at what the experts are doing and copy it. They know what to do but not why it should be done...they know how to apply complex processes and techniques and have been well trained but do not understand the limits of those techniques.** (Curtis Faith, *Way of the Turtle*, 2007)

Another said:

> ***Genuine experts*** know an exceeding amount and may intimidate others into silence. *Pseudo experts* annoy others by acting as though they know a lot about the topic. (Vaughn, Schumm, and Sinagub, *Focus Group Interviews in Education and Psychology*, 1996)

Looking at the literature, when using *pseudo*-, there seems to be some latitude in choosing whether to use a hyphen, use a space, or form a single word.

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario sounds like a *Jack of all trades, master of none*.

Note that the first half of the sentence generally (and originally) connotes positive notions about a person's abilities. The second half of the sentence however, [came later](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_all_trades,_master_of_none#.22Master_of_none.22), to deliver the notion that Jack really is no subject matter expert

Additionally, you may consider prefixing a noun with *faux* (or *pseudo* like in the previous answer). Taking the word *polymath* for example (which is what describes an expert in multiple fields), you could then have a *faux-polymath* or *faux-expert*